# write a sql stored procedure to delete the data from the table within the i day

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a simple application which stores the data into the sql server database table named student table .The design of the table is as follows 3 colums. name ,sex and registeredtime(datetime).In my WPF window i have three fields to insert the data into the table.Now i want to have the delete button based on the input given by the user(which is a datetimepicker).

How to delete the data from the table which is 1 day in london timing old compared to the date given by the user. ?

I want to have a stored procedure which i can call from the c# code.i am able to try some thing like this but Select * from studenttable where registereddate < GetDate()-7 but i am unable to achieve what i am supposed to ...

Comment: Try some Dateadd or DateDiff functions in SQL

Answer (score 2):

Read this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189794.aspx

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(day, datecolumn, getdate()) < 1
```

It's best to have a play around with this using SELECT before going for the DELETE. I believe the order is important, e.g. DATEDIFF(day, datecolumn, getdate()) is different to DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), datecolumn).

EDIT: (see Sean Lange's comments)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datecolumn < dateadd(day, -@Parameter, getdate())
```

Comment: This works but is nonSARGable because you have datecolumn in a function in the where clause. It would be much better to rearrange a little bit the column is outside the function. where datecolumn < dateadd(day, -@Parameter, getdate())

Comment: Wow! I've never heard of non-sargable before. Just read up on it, can't believe I didn;t know that. Every day's a school day.